# PUT method callback,what result.result actually does?

Tags: node.js, express

I am struggling to fully comprehend how the OP performed callback

```
const db = mongoskin.db('mongodb://@localhost:27017/test')

const id = mongoskin.helper.toObjectID

app.param('collectionName', (req, res, next, collectionName) => {
    req.collection = db.collection(collectionName)
    return next()
})
```

What result.result.n does?

PUT method

```
app.put('/collections/:collectionName/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  req.collection.update({_id: id(req.params.id)},
    {$set: req.body},
    {safe: true, multi: false}, (e, result) => {
      if (e) return next(e)
      res.send((result.result.n === 1) ? {msg: 'success'} : {msg: 'error'})
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.n` contains the [number of documents selected for update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#update.n) by the `req.collection.update` function. Checking it against one (`result.result.n === 1`) is used as a measure of successful operation (if and only if just one document if affected by update command, sends success to client).